# Get XPath data for a bound repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xpath, xml-parsing, repeater

I have a Repeater element in my .aspx file that calls a bind sub in my CodeBehind on my OnItemDataBound event, similar to this:

```
Sub SomeRepeaterBinder(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    (code binding data to repeater form objects goes here)
    :
    (etc.)
```

For the most part, it works great, but here's the problem I'm trying to solve: if there is no data, I want it to either (1) hide the repeater item, or (2) exit the sub completely (or maybe both).

In order to do that, I need to know whether or not any data exists in my Repeater item.  And despite reading loads of documentation about RepeaterItemEventArgs properties (and running lots of debuggers), I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax.

Can someone help me out with this?  I'm hoping this is an easy question with an easy answer.

Note: my data source is XML.  My form objects and my Repeater data source have XPaths assigned to them.  I'm working with VB.

Thanks in advance . . .

Comment: I'm thinking I'd need to implement e.Item.DataItem in some way, shape, or form.

Comment: Posting this for my personal reference -- this link seems helpful: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?594642-get-datavalue-of-repeater-item-DataItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer for this, but here's how I got it to work.

I didn't use e.Item.DataItem at all.  I took the XML data source for my repeater and used selectSingleNode (using the data source XPath) to return my value.  If the resulting string is empty, I hide the row.

However, if anyone has a more elegant or robust answer, I'm all ears.